# Working domain with no NS records, how is it possible?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-zone, cloudflare

I was checking a domain on cloudflare.

```
webroot.bitappii.com
```

There is no NS records for this domain on whois. Only SOA and A records. How this is possible that a working domain has no NS records.

Whois only shows

```
webroot.bitappii.com    SOA 1800        kenneth.ns.cloudflare.com dns@cloudflare.com 2038211396 10000 2400 604800 3600
webroot.bitappii.com    A   300     104.26.2.141
webroot.bitappii.com    A   300     172.67.70.46
webroot.bitappii.com    A   300     104.26.3.141
webroot.bitappii.com    AAAA    300     2606:4700:20::681a:28d
webroot.bitappii.com    AAAA    300     2606:4700:20::ac43:462e
webroot.bitappii.com    AAAA    300     2606:4700:20::681a:38d
```

Comment: `dig +noall +answer ns bitappii.com`
bitappii.com.           86400   IN      NS      ursula.ns.cloudflare.com.
bitappii.com.           86400   IN      NS      kenneth.ns.cloudflare.com.  The NS records are in the root servers.  They should also be added to the zone file to prevent potential future issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"bitappii.com" has NS records. You don't need separate NS records for subdomains unless you want them to be served by different set of DNS servers.

```
$ dig NS bitappii.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.15-Debian <<>> NS bitappii.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 44779
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;bitappii.com.                  IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
bitappii.com.           86400   IN      NS      kenneth.ns.cloudflare.com.
bitappii.com.           86400   IN      NS      ursula.ns.cloudflare.com.

;; Query time: 48 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 06 13:44:31 IST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 98
```

Comment: Thanks. It was not shown in who.is, so I wondered. I didn't dig.